# Change Icon of a Discord Guild using Discord.Js

Tags: discord, discord.js

In the discord.js documentation, I found that you can only change the server icon by defining the server icon variable that you're going to use as a base64 string/buffer. \

I want to edit the guild and set a specific server icon. 
Someone can help me doing this? \

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setIcon` method from the `Guild` class for example -

```js
message.guild.setIcon("Some URL")
```